# I try to retain the input but InvalidFormatException was thrown

Tags: java, input, apache-poi

I would like to retain the data in the existing excel file.After that then try to output something to this file.But I got an error.

I have been searching the answer but none of it matches my situation.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class TryHyperlink{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File in = new File("D:\\Test1.xlsx");

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(in);
//read input
            XSSFWorkbook wb;
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);//The StackTrace shows that the error is here
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.iterator();
//iterate through every row and cell
            while(rowItr.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowItr.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellItr = row.iterator();
                while(cellItr.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellItr.next();

                }
            }
            fin.close();
//close the input stream so output stream can write
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(in);
            wb.write(fout);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> **Edit:**
>   After referring to Alex Richter Comment,I closed the output stream and the error gone.  Now Another error come out:
>   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred *and so on*(the link of the photo at the bottom of the question)

````
package net.excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class TryHyperlink{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File in = new File("D:\\penril.xlsx");

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(in);

            XSSFWorkbook wb;
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.iterator();

            while(rowItr.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowItr.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellItr = row.iterator();
                while(cellItr.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellItr.next();
                    cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
            }
            fin.close();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(in);
            wb.write(fout);
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```package net.excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class TryHyperlink{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File in = new File("D:\\penril.xlsx");

        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(in);

            XSSFWorkbook wb;
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowItr = sheet.iterator();

            while(rowItr.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowItr.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellItr = row.iterator();
                while(cellItr.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellItr.next();
                    cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
            }
            fin.close();
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(in);
            wb.write(fout);
            fout.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTOn3.png
````

Comment: Are you sure that your file is actually `.xlsx` and not `.xls`?

Comment: Yes it is `.xlsx` But, initially the file are able to open ,after I run the program, error come out: `Excel cannot open the file 'Test1.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.`

Comment: I guess your file `D:\Test1.xlsx` got corrupted because you do not closing your `FileOutputStream fout`. Do `... wb.write(fout); fout.close(); ...`. But since the file is corrupted now, start with a new proper file created by `Excel`.

Comment: Ok now the file is not corrupted anymore. But another error comeout. Please  refer to the question again.Thanks!

Comment: What `apache poi` version is used together with what `Java` version? See https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N102B0. Using `Java 11` you will get such warnings if old `apache poi` versions (prior `4.1.0`) are used. Do using latest stable version always, which currently is `4.1.0`. I do so and I can use `Java 11` together with `apache poi 4.1.0` without such warnings.

Comment: Ya I am not using the latest `apache poi` while I am using `Java 11`. Now the problem solved, Thank you !